# Logic Apps - Populate a Microsoft Word template changing font size

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, workflow, azure-logic-apps

I am using the Populate a Microsoft Word template action in a workflow. I'm populating a few tags throughout a document that is about 3 pages long. In the word template the font is Arial 10 for the entire document. However, when the word template has gone through the workflow and then saved in SharePoint a couple of the tags as well as a couple of random paragraphs change to size 11 font.

I tried changing the font to size 9 in the places it was consistently being sized up but then when the document generated it stayed size 9.

Is there anything I can do to the document or the action in the workflow to ensure the content stays the same when its saved to SharePoint?

Populate a Microsoft Word template action:
[image]

Comment: The solution is to use Word _Typestyles_ instead of local formatting. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-styles-advantage-in-word-b4a6372f-188c-93cb-831b-c4dd0cb3a881

Comment: That worked!! Thank you

Comment: Hello, I have posted an answer so that others can find it more easily. If you are willing to post more detailed steps, I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `John Korchok` said in the comments, you should use `Word Typestyles` instead of local formatting.